# How to create a new list where new_array[i][j] = b[a[i][j]] (with a being an array and b a vector) without using for loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, knn, array-broadcasting

I have two arrays, for example `a = np.array([[0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 0]])` and `b = np.array([1, 1, 2])`.
What I want to do is to create a new array with the same size of a, but where each entry (i,j) corresponds to the value of list b with the index given by `a[i][j]`. Formally, I want `new_list[i][j] = b[a[i][j]]`.

I know that this can be achieved with for loops, as shown in the code below. However, I wanted to ask if this is possible to do without for loops and only with Numpy or Python built-in functions using code vectorization.

```
a = np.array([[0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 0]])
b = np.array([0, 0, 2])
new_array = np.empty((2,3))
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(3):
        new_array[i][j] = b[a[i][j]]
```

expected output:

```
array([[0, 2, 0],
       [0, 2, 0]])
```

Comment: In python, `list` and `array` (short for `numpy.ndarray`) are distinct classes.  I prefer than subject lines and variable names didn't confuse the two.  In your code, `a` and `b` are lists, `new_list` is an array.  It can be indexed with `new_list[i,j]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.take`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html):

```
np.take(b, a)
```

output:

```
array([[0, 2, 0],
       [0, 2, 0]])
```

##### non ambiguous example

```
a = [[0, 2, 0], [1, 1, 2]]
b = [6, 7, 8]
np.take(b, a)

# array([[6, 8, 6],
#        [7, 7, 8]])
```